# Digit sequence that is not prime in any base

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there a sequence of base-$b$ digits of length greater than one with all digits $\ne 0$ that does *not* represent a prime number in *any* base?

**Example:** $12_{10}=12$ is not prime, but $12_3=5$ is.

Comment: "In *any* base" implies that all digits must be $1$ (otherwise, the sequence will not make any sense on base $2$).

Comment: In any base > 4 (such that the digit exists), "4" is not prime. QED?

Comment: "length greater than one"... that's why "1" doesn't work.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

$121$. Suppose it is prime in base $b$. Then $b^2+2b+1=(b+1)(b+1)$ is prime.

Comment: Interesting, then, that $11^2=121$ no matter what base you are using. (Well, not base $2$, because then $121$ is meaningless.)

Comment: @KSmarts:  that is correct.  In fact any multiplication that doesn't carry remains true in all bases.  So $11 \cdot 12 = 132$ in all bases greater than $3$.

Comment: In base $2$ this number is not defined.

Answer (score 39):

$112$ is always divisible by $2$ for bases above base $2$

$1111=11\times 101$ in any base.

Comment: Oh, this is great. An example with only the digit $1$, it works in all bases, (even base $1$) since it is $4$.

Comment: @JorgeFernández Base 1? What's that?

Comment: you just add the number of digits.

Comment: @JorgeFernández: For base 1 to be useful, you have to bend the rules a bit. Base **N** only allows digits from 0 to **N**-1; base 1 would only allow the digit 0.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant, base 0 is like using scratchmarks.

Answer (score 6):

The smallest example (unless you are in base 2) is $22=2 \cdot 11$

Answer (score 4):

If $d_nd_{n-1}\ldots d_0$ is a string of digits, it is convenient to consider the polynomial $f(x)=d_nx^n+d_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+d_0$. Then $(d_nd_{n-1}\ldots d_0)_b=f(b)$. The OP's question is related to the question "Which integer polynomials take only composite values?".

The answers given so far describe two different phenomena (both illustrated in Mark Bennet's answer).

1. If $f(x)$ factors as a polynomial, then $f(b)$ is composite for all sufficiently large $b$. For example, $1111_b=101_b\cdot 11_b$ is composite for all $b$, which is equivalent to the polynomial factorization $x^3+x^2+x+1=(x^2+1)(x+1)$.
2. Sometimes there is a particular prime $p$ that divides $f(x)$ for all integers $x$. For instance, $2$ always divides $112_b$ (equivalently, $2\big|\,f(b)$, where $f(x)=x^2+x+2$).

The [Bunyakovsky conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) would imply that these are the only reasons a polynomial takes only composite values.

> **Conjecture**: Let $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be non-constant with positive leading coefficient. Suppose:
>
> - $f(x)$ is irreducible, and
> - there is no integer $d>1$ such that $d\,\big|\,f(b)$ for all integers $b$.
>
> Then $f(b)$ is prime for infinitely many positive integers $b$.

There are deterministic algorithms for checking whether a given polynomial satisfies the hypotheses of this conjecture.

Answer (score 3):

Extending Jorge's example, 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}b^k}=(b+1)^n$$
is not prime in any base large enough to have the binomial coefficients as digits.

Comment: It has to have a non-zero digit

Comment: @JorgeFernández: It has to have **all** digits non-zero (according to the question at hand).

Comment: Oh yeah, that's what I would have wrote if my brain didn't suddenly space out.

Answer (score 0):

How about $121$.  We have $1b^2+2b+1=(b+1)^2$.

Similarly for $1331$ we have $1b^3+3b^2+3b+1=(b+1)^3$.